# Calculate maximum difference between grouped rows

Tags: sas

I have the following data where people in households are sorted by age (oldest to youngest):

```
data houses;             
input HouseID PersonID Age;       
datalines;              
1 1 25                    
1 2 20                   
2 1 32
2 2 16
2 3 14
2 4 12
3 1 44
3 2 42
3 3 10
3 4 5
;
run;
```

I would like to calculate for each household the maximum age difference between consecutively aged people. So this example would give values of 5 (=25-20), 16 (=32-16) and 32 (=42-10) for households 1, 2 and 3 consecutively.

I could do this using lots of merges (i.e. extract person 1, merge with extract of person 2, and so on), but as there can be upto 20+ people in a household I'm looking for a much more direct method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a two pass solution. Same first step as  the two solutions above, sort by age. In the second step keep track of max_diff per row, at the last record of HouseID output the results. This results in only two passes through the data.

```
proc sort data=houses; by houseid age;run;

data want;
set houses;
by houseID;

retain max_diff 0;

diff = dif1(age)*-1;

if first.HouseID then do;
    diff = .; max_diff=.;
end;

if diff>max_diff then max_diff=diff;
if last.houseID then output;

keep houseID max_diff;
run;
```

Comment: Just be careful with the sort at the beginning, the OP states that it should be by descending age.  It works here as personid appears to be assigned in order of the eldest person first, however it may not be the case with the real data.

Comment: You're correct, I just copied and pasted the initial code. I'll edit the solution, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
proc sort data=houses; by houseid personid age;run;

data _t1;
set houses;
diff = dif1(age) * (-1);
if personid = 1 then diff = .;
run;


proc sql;
create table want as 
select houseid, max(diff) as Max_Diff
from _t1
group by houseid;
```

Comment: Just be careful with the sort at the beginning, the OP states that it should be by descending age.  It works here as personid appears to be assigned in order of the eldest person first, however it may not be the case with the real data.

Comment: Good comment. In this case personid is attributed via a sort by descending age within the household, but for other users' problems this may not be the case.

Comment: An answer that is entirely code is not considered a good answer generally.  Answers should explain how/why they work - and in fact that part of the answer is _more_ important than the code.

Answer (score 2):

```
proc sort data = house;
 by houseid descending age;
run;

data house;
set house;
by houseid;
lag_age = lag1(age);
if first.houseid then age_diff = 0;
age_diff = lag_age - age;
run;

proc sql;
 select houseid,max(age_diff) as max_age_diff
 from house
 group by houseid;
quit;
```

Working:

First sort the data set using houseid and descending Age. 
Second data step will calculate difference between current age value (in PDV) and previous age value in PDV. Then, using sql procedure, we can get the max age difference for each houseid.

Comment: Many thanks. From this I would just need to add a dummy value to the oldest person in each house, as age_diff for these people is calculated by subtracting their age from the youngest person of the previous household i.e. in this example age_diff for person 1 of house 3 is calculated as -32. This could lead to errors, for example if the youngest person of house 2 was aged 80, then age_diff would = 36, and thus max(age_diff) would be 36 instead of the correct value of 32.

Answer (score 2):

Just throwing one more into the mix. This one is a condensed version of Reeza's response.

```
/* No need to sort by PersonID as age is the only concern */
proc sort data = houses;
    by HouseID Age;
run;
data want;
    set houses;
    by HouseID;
    /* Keep the diff when a new row is loaded */
    retain diff;
    /* Only replace the diff if it is larger than previous */
    diff = max(diff, abs(dif(Age)));
    /* Reset diff for each new house */
    if first.HouseID then diff = 0;
    /* Only output the final diff for each house */
    if last.HouseID;
    keep HouseID diff;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using [FIRST. and LAST.](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001349233.htm) with one pass (after sort) through the data.

```
data houses;             
 input HouseID PersonID Age;       
 datalines;              
1 1 25                    
1 2 20                   
2 1 32
2 2 16
2 3 14
2 4 12
3 1 44
3 2 42
3 3 10
3 4 5
;
run;

Proc sort data=HOUSES;
 by houseid descending age ;
run;

Data WANT(keep=houseid max_diff);
 format houseid max_diff;
 retain max_diff age1 age2;
 Set HOUSES;

 by houseid descending age ;

 if first.houseid and last.houseid then do;
  max_diff=0;
  output;
 end;
 else if first.houseid then do;
  call missing(max_diff,age1,age2);
  age1=age;
 end;
 else if not(first.houseid or last.houseid) then do;
  age2=age;
  temp=age1-age2;
  if temp>max_diff then max_diff=temp;
  age1=age;  
 end;
 else if last.houseid then do;
  age2=age;
  temp=age1-age2;
  if temp>max_diff then max_diff=temp;
  output;
 end;
Run;
```